# Yahoo profile API sending JSONP result through RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, yahoo-api

I am facing a odd issue when I am calling Yahoo user profile API using parameter format with xml value yahoo is sending JSONP (JSON covered with parenthesis `(<JSON>);`) result but when i send this request though Google chrome's postman plugin Yahoo api is sending XML result.

API is :

> http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{guid}/profile

Doc : http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/extended-profile-resource.html

My code

```
 public string RestApiInvoke(string url, TRANSPORT_METHOD method, Dictionary<string, string> data, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            RestRequest request;

            if (method == TRANSPORT_METHOD.POST)
            {
                request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            }
            else
            {
                request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            }

            if (data.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
            {
                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    request.AddParameter(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }

            if (headers.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
            {
                foreach (var item in headers)
                {
                    request.AddHeader(item.Key, item.Value);
                }
            }

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            return response.Content;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer, set just `Accept` header `text/xml`, actually RestSharp uses Accept something like `application/json text/html text/xml` so Yahoo picks first one and send JSONP result. I have set it manually using following code.

```
headers.Add("Accept", "text/xml");
```